# No Sound/Mic on Phone Calls

Tags: samsung, calls, samsung-galaxy-s-7-edge

I have a Samsung S7 Edge (its a refurbished model). Everything works fine besides for making calls over the network... I can ring, and receive calls but when the connection is established we both cannot hear each other.

I have debugged by:

- Using whatsapp to make a call (works) - which proves the
  microphone/speaker both work.
- Used a different network sim (doesn't work).
- Tried ringing the other person (doesn't work).
- Tried receiving the call (doesn't work).
- SMS works (sending and receiving).

What can I do to fix this problem?

Comment: Try different app for calling? And if already using one check whether it has  Microphone permission granted.

Comment: Tried, and no luck :(

Comment: There was some [problem](https://www.ifixit.com/Answers/View/189655/No+sound+or+mic+during+calls+only.) with S4 too. Dig more into search engine. The problem may lie with Phone Services, which is the system app for managing calls.